# Time format on pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a file with 15 columns, the first 5 are date and time columns `["year", "month", "day", "hour", "min"...]`, I want to combine the two time columns so that they are one column of time with format "H:M" so that it is easy for me to select data for a specific time range, e.g 19:00 - 24:00.

I have searched for a solution but all that shows up does not work and it's all on how to deal with date instead of time.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of `datetime` objects, which makes working with date and time objects very simple. In fact, `pandas.to_datetime` is built to parse columns exactly as you have. (You need at least a year, month and day column for this parsing to work)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2001, 2012],
                   'month': [1, 12],
                   'day': [16, 19],
                   'hour': [1, 23],
                   'minutes': [5, 35],
                   'val1': [1.23, 1.151]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minutes']])
print(df)
#   year  month  day  hour  minutes   val1                Date
#0  2001      1   16     1        5  1.230 2001-01-16 01:05:00
#1  2012     12   19    23       35  1.151 2012-12-19 23:35:00
```

Then, if you are willing to set it as your `index` you can use the built in functionality of `between_time`.

```
df.set_index('Date').between_time('19:00', '23:40')
#                     year  month  day  hour  minutes   val1
#Date                                                       
#2012-12-19 23:35:00  2012     12   19    23       35  1.151
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose df is your data frame with those 5 columns.  You need to create a new column and set it to be equal to hour + ":" + minutes.

```
df['time'] = (df['hour'].astype(str) + ":" + df['min'].astype(str))
```

`astype(str)` is not necessary if `df['hour']` and `df['min']` are type string in your pandas dataframe.